# Checking if a newly created file exists in AWS S3 using aws-sdk ruby gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using aws-sdk ruby gem (v 1.66.0) to upload a file to S3

`bucket = AWS::S3.new.buckets[@bucket_name]
obj = bucket.objects['/path/to/file_to_upload.pdf']
obj.write(:file => "/file_to_upload.pdf").exists? # => false`

Even though the file "file_to_upload.pdf" does get uploaded to the designated path, calling `.exists?` on the object returns false.

This only happened on the production environment. Running the same code in our QA environment returned `true`. I am assuming it is some kind of permissions issue, but I couldn't find an answer how to change this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a while, it seems that ObjectVersioning was turned on in AWS S3 for the production bucket. When ObjectVersioning is turned on, calling `obj.write(:file => "/file_to_upload.pdf")` returns ObjectVersion, which does not have `.exists?` method defined. When ObjectVersioning is turned off, `obj.write(:file => "/file_to_upload.pdf")` returns Object which has `.exists?` method.

Weird and inconsistent but I hope this helps for anyone else out there.